# ActionbarSherlock Tab Navigation

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Hello I am using actionbarsherlock in my project, and I would like to have two mapviews separated by tabs using the tabbed navigation in the actionbar. Is there a workaround to this without using fragments?

Thank You

Comment: What's wrong with `Fragment`s?

Comment: from what I understand you can't use fragments with Mapview

Comment: You are going to have to use fragments, it's how `ActionBarSherlock` works with `MapView`

Comment: `two mapviews` not recommended as Your app should only have One `mapView`. Think of a different approach..

Comment: basically its the same mapview with a different overlay..

Comment: You can use fragments with Google Maps for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial will help you create two tabs with two different `MapView`s if you so choose:

http://blog.xavirigau.com/?p=39

Comment: hmm ok i will try this and comment here the results

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can help?

```
 ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
 getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
```

From one of Jake Wharton's demos: [TabNavigation](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java).  (You can view all demos [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos))

Comment: yes i have seen the sample, but again, he uses fragments.. and we cant use TabActivity because the method is deprecated in the library